# How to solve this problem from install error

Tags: python, list, installation, pip, runtime-error

```
pip install pandas --pre  
  Using cached pandas-2.1.0.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d\.mesonpy-t_en0olc\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d\.mesonpy-t_en0olc\build\meson-python-native-file.ini 
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.0.1
      Source dir: C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d
      Build dir: C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d\.mesonpy-t_en0olc\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.0
     
      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe        
     
      A full log can be found at C:\TEMP\pip-install-z0_0skv2\pandas_0e513c02a1e4406d845be40ba34f7a2d\.mesonpy-t_en0olc\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

ABOVE is my error message.

I have tried :

1. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`.
2. add `--pre`.
3. download again

But it is no way to succeed.

Comment: Your error message states `ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe`. Have you checked if that file is there? If not, I would suggest you check that your visual studio installation is valid.

Comment: What is your python version? You should try to install a pandas version that does not require source compilation

Comment: @飛行櫃員 I couldn't find this thing after checking ，version is 3.11.2

Comment: Can you try `pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Pandas 2.1.3 requires a minimum Python version of 3.9. Please check if your Python version is not lower than that. I resolved it by installing the latest Python version.

By the way, you also need to install the new Python version and update the Python environment variables. For example, specify the path to the new Python version in the environment variables, such as C:\Python\Python312\ and C:\Python\Python312\Scripts. After that, check if it is set correctly by using python -V. Once you do this, the pip install pandas command should probably work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error using Python 32-bit, and I resolved it by downloading a 64-bit version of Python.

When you install any library using pip, pip checks for pre-compiled versions of the library, which are called 'wheels'. If it can't find a version that is compatible with your hardware/operating system and your Python version, it will try to build the required code using a local toolchain.

If it can't find a toolchain, this error will occur.

So, there are multiple solutions:

- Try to download another version of Python (above 3.9 for Pandas 2.1.3) that matches your system architecture (32-bit, 64-bit, ARM64). Be sure that you use the correct python version using the command `python --version`
- Use Anaconda, which uses pre-packaged Pandas code (repo.anaconda.com).
- Install a toolchain for C/C++ (such as Microsoft Visual Studio). You may need to specify your compiler location in the pip configuration.